# SonarQube 4.3.3 file exclusion not working

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I build my code and invoke SONAR analysis through Jenkins.
I want to ignore all the folder/files from SONAR code analysis that fall under the 'target' folder of my code. I have already tried the following things:

1. added '**/target/**' under the SONAR's Settings > Exclusions, restarted the SONAR server. But i am getting following error

> [ERROR] Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project : Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
>   [ERROR] **/target/** [ERROR] ^

2. added '\\*\\*/target/\\*\\*' under the SONAR's Settings > Exclusions, to avoid the previos error.
3. added 'sonar.exclusions=**/target/**' in sonar.properties file.

But SONAR is still analyzing the code under the "target" folder and under all its sub-folders.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is :

```
sonar.exclusions=target/**
```

(or just `target/**` is you set it through the UI)

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I also tried putting 'target/**' in UI but i got "Dangling meta character '*' " error. To avoid error i did 'target/\\\*\\\*', this neither gave me error nor excluded the target folder.

Comment: Iam also facing same issue.. Is it resolved? **/angular.*.js

Answer (score 1):

The pattern should be

```
    -Dsonar.exclusions=**/target/**
```